# timeout: timed out receiving message from renderer - Chrome Driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

We are receiving the titled error intermittently (around 20% of the time) on random tests in our test suite with no apparent link.

Latest chrome and latest chrome driver.

Looking at the reported bug - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=402&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=

Chromium are denying that it is an issue, whilst the community is reporting otherwise.

All workarounds mentioned in the thread have been tried to no success.

Has anyone else encountered this rather annoying issue, and has anyone come across a valid workaround.

Is it possible to write an extension method to simply catch these exceptions, re-instantiate the driver and retry ?

Comment: Try different combinations of versions for selenium with chrome driver and see when is working better. start with the latest versions, possible this is an issue because chrome has updated an you might have some compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

After more investigation this happened on navigates.

Fixed by implementing the below extension method:

```
    public static void NavigateToAndRetry(this IWebDriver driver, string url)
    {
        try
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
        }
        catch (WebDriverTimeoutException exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Caught {0}, refreshing {1}", exception, url);
            driver.Navigate().Refresh();
        }
    }
```